# How do I make OS/2 Warp bootable USB?

Tags: thinkpad

I want to install OS/2 Warp on my ThinkPad x60, but I can't use CD because I've run out. I am wondering if anybody knows how to make a setup USB?

Thanks,
Gabe

Comment: In my experience - you cannot get the first stage to boot without a *floppy*  - might be better with the latter day ecomstation and blue lion distros. Even on a VM, installing it is *extraordinarily difficult* on 'modern' hardware.

Comment: @fixer1234 Thanks. I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score -1):

Try http://unetbootin.org/. For me it worked with nearly every image but i dont know how OS/2 Warp works. I only tried it with recent operating systems.

Comment: This seems massively speculative.